# VideoJS ASS não funciona em páginas com RewriteRule

Tags: php, plugin, reprodutor-de-video

Eu uso `RewriteRule (.*) /index.php [QSA,L]` e para gerenciar as URLs uso esse código:

```php
<?php

$url = ltrim( parse_url( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] , PHP_URL_PATH ) , '/' );
$url = explode( '/' , $url );

if(count($url) == 1)
{
if(file_exists(DIR_PAGES.$url[0].'.php'))
{
    if($url[0] == 'home')
    {
        $pag = DIR_PAGES.'home.php';
    }
    else
    {
        $pag = DIR_PAGES.$url[0].'.php';
    }
}
else if(file_exists(DIR_PAGES.$url[0]) && $url[0] != '')
{
    header('Location: '.SITE_URL.substr($url[0], 0, -4));
}
else if($url[0] == '' || $url[0] == null)
{
    $pag = DIR_PAGES.'home.php';
}
else
{
    header('Location: '.SITE_URL);
}
}
else if(count($url) == 2)
{
if($url[0] == 'stream' || $url[0] == 'newstream')
{
    if($url[1] != '' || $url[1] != null)
    {
        if($url[0] == 'stream')
        {
            $pag = DIR_PAGES.'stream.php';
        }
        else
        {
            $pag = DIR_PAGES.'newstream.php';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        header('Location: '.SITE_URL);
    }
}
else
{
    header('Location: '.SITE_URL);
}
}
```

Estou usando, porém quando acesso *site.com/newstream/algumnome* o VideoJS ASS para de funcionar.

```
    videojs('player', {
    controls: true,
    nativeControlsForTouch: false,
    fluid: true,
    plugins: {
      ass: {
        'src': ["./vjs/002.ass"],
        'delay': 0
      }
    },
    sources: [{"type": "video/mp4", "src": "/files/video.mkv"}]
    });
```

Comment: E esse VideoJS ASS faz requisição a algum arquivo do servidor?

Comment: Faz, do arquivo de legenda, tentei com link direto `site.com/files/arquivo.ass` e com link desde a raiz `/var/www/site/files/arquivo.ass`, porem não funcionou.

Comment: Porque você está direcionando todas as URLs para o `index.php`. Tente adicionar algo como `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:ass)$ [NC]` no seu `.htaccess` e veja se muda algo.

Comment: Ainda não resolveu, como posso resolver isso mudando meu .htaccess, nem que tenha que mudar ele por completo, eu apenas quero que quando alguém acesse `site.com/stream/algumnome`, eu consiga pegar o valor `algumnome` rodando o arquivo stream.php

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Lembrando que eu defino o `src` do VideoJS na mesma pagina e funciona perfeitamente.

Comment: E como seria isso? Pode postar o código?

Comment: Pronto, já coloquei o código na pergunta.

Comment: E se não definir o `src` na mesma página, como o VideoJS sabe qual arquivo buscar?

Comment: Não entendi oque você quer saber com sua pergunta, poderia explicar melhor ??

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58288/discussion-between-anderson-carlos-woss-and-lucas-carezia).