# Erro 404 ao acessar arquivo com .htaccess

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite

Por enquanto eu estou com o seguinte `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME}\.php !-d

RewriteRule ^index.php\/(.*)$ pages/$1.php
RewriteRule ^stream\/(.*)$ /pages/stream.php?a=$1
ErrorDocument 404 /pages/404.php
```

Eu tenho os seguintes arquivos

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando eu acesso `site.com/outra` ele retorna erro 404, como posso arrumar isso?

Comment: Acontece porque a URL acessada não casa com nenhum padrão definido no arquivo. Você chegou a estudar [esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/202764/5878)?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Sim, cheguei a usar o exemplo dele para construir a regra `RewriteRule ^stream\/(.*)$ /pages/stream.php?a=$1`, tanto que quando eu acesso `site.com/stream/algo` ele funciona perfeitamente, porem quando eu acesso `site.com/outra` não funciona.

Comment: Quando troco a regra `RewriteRule ^index.php\/(.*)$ pages/$1.php` para `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ pages/$1.php` a pagina `site.com/outra` começa a  funcionar, porem `site.com/stream/algo` para de funcionar junto com `site.com`(index.php).

Comment: Lá eu tive a duvida sobre como usar 2 argumentos, aqui eu quero saber o por que de não conseguir acessar arquivos com o htaccess, acho que você está equivocado quando a duplicata.

Comment: Talvez. Você não está mais utilizando o `index.php` que você definiu [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/202715/videojs-ass-n%C3%A3o-funciona-em-p%C3%A1ginas-com-rewriterule)?

Comment: Não, meu index está completamente vazio. Criei um projeto apenas para teste, por isso  as minhas duvidas.

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/202943/5878